# how to send cross domain post message in safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, postmessage

According to [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging) Safari 9 support Cross domain postMessage but when I try to send message to different domain I've got exception about origin.

I have code like this:

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
// this line throw exception
var win = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow;
a.onclick = function() {
    var obj = {message: input.value};
    sysend.broadcast('foo', obj);
    // proxy to send message to other domains using hidden iframe
    win.postMessage(JSON.stringify({key: 'foo', data: obj}), "*");
};
```

the page that show this error is http://jcubic.pl/sysend.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Safari throw exception when accessing contentWindow first time, it work after second time:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var win;
try {
    win = iframe.contentWindow;
} catch(e) {
    win = iframe.contentWindow;
}
```

Comment: Does this example still work in Safari? It seems that Safari doesn't allow cross-domain communication with iframes in [sysend.js](https://github.com/jcubic/sysend.js/).

Comment: @AndersonGreen Cross-Domain communication doesn't work anymore. But I think this was working before they added 3rd party limitation. This works as it doesn't throw an exception. But the LS was not working. I don't remember about BroacastChannel if I tested this API in Safari. I need to investigate.