# postMessage giving "Blocked frame" error, but only in Safari

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari

I am using postMessage to share data between https://www.example.com (Which I'll call mainSite) and https://subdomain.example.com (which I'll call subSite)

subSite has an iframe to mainSite,

subSite's code looks something like:

```js
//set the src of the iframe
$("#main-site-iframe").attr("src", "https://www.example.com");
//wait for the main site page to open
$("#main-site-iframe")[0].onload = () => {
    //my page posts a message to their site
    $("#my-iframe")[0].contentWindow.postMessage("messagePlox", "https://www.example.com");  
};

//wait for the iframe to message back
window.addEventListener('message', iframeResponse, false);
function iframeResponse(e) {
    //make sure the request is from the correct site
    if(e.origin == 'https://www.example.com')
    {
        //Got the data
        console.log(e.data);
    }
}
```

mainSite looks like this:

```
//listen for the subdomain to make a request
window.addEventListener('message', subdomainRequest, false);
function subdomainRequest(e) {
    //make sure the request is from the correct subdomain
    if(e.origin == 'https://subdomain.example.com')
    {
        //respond with the data
        e.source.postMessage("We got you", e.origin);
    }
}
```

The problem with the above is that it works in every browser EXCEPT Safari which refuses it and says:

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.example.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://subdomain.example.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Which seems to imply the response back is breaking since mainSite is trying to "access" subSite.

Does anyone know why this would only happen in Safari and not in Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: At first glance there is nothing in there that should trigger any cross-origin check anyway... You sure it's all you have? From which page the error fires? Can you try to pin point exactly which line triggers it? What if you use the wildcard `"*"` as destination-origin for postMessage? Do you have any plugins installed in this browser? What version of Safari is this?

Comment: @Kaiido I will attempt to change the origin to wildcard on subSite, I have already tried asking them to change it on mainSite and it did not work. Acording to the error, it seems that mainSite is triggering the error. I am not sure about plugins, I am a windows user, so I didn't experience the error until I sent it to another team who had a mac I will ask, but there were multiple reports from different users and I assume they didn't all have the same plugins. Most likely latest version, again not sure.

Comment: @Kaiido Update to this, using wildcard did not fix it in safari, it still worked for all browsers. Safari version was latest, also happens on latest iOS update safari unfortunately I am no longer working on the project. As of me leaving the project the only solution was to have a fallback option where they added a regular login form instead of sharing a token with the main site. Still really curious why this was the case.

Comment: Could also have been a simple `console.log( event )`

Comment: This tree house codepen is a good tool https://codepen.io/matt-west/full/lpExI spoiler alert... it doesn't work on Safari. There appears to be some requirement that the Parent be near the domain of the child. `Unable to post message to http://demos.mattwest.io. Recipient has origin https://cdpn.io.`

Answer (score 3):

**Two-way cross-domain** iFrame communication is usually blocked in Safari/Opera. The primary way around this is using a gateway that the parent and child both agree on... but they cannot using IPC use network-less messages to communicate bidirectionally. Alternatively, There are some exceptions that are closely guarded by the Nitro JS engine team, it appears if you have a large iFrame and the user is interacting with it, the messages from the parent will go through, and vise versa.

Messages that come from the parent get handled as if they are in a SW... that is to say don't expect things to work normally in the handler... test a lot. My promise resolve function for instance, can't be called from a message handling function for some reason... Which means I have to check to see if the function has been called in a time out, making things, painfully slow.

If you just need to show a success message from the child, you could do this:

```
parent.sendSuccessMsg();

function sendSuccessMsg(){
    document.getElementById('iframeID').src="http://example.com/?successData=123";
}
```

Otherwise, you can use websockets with a gateway to mingle cross-domain. There seems to be some sort of undocumented exception if you load the iFrame twice, and the message is sent early on iframe load.

Source: https://benohead.com/blog/2015/12/07/cross-document-communication-with-iframes/
Bug/Failsafe Discovery: [how to send cross domain post message in safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632188/how-to-send-cross-domain-post-message-in-safari)